# Kinetic Scrolling in ViewPager android (Like listView)

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-viewpager

I need my ViewPager to act like ListView, I mean if you start scrolling and took finger off listview proceed scrolling for some time. Maybe, somehow You know how to implement this in ViewPager?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try HorizontalScrollView?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html